# maya export to flash 10

Tags: flash, actionscript, maya

Adobe released flash 10 with 3d support but I can't seem to find any good information on how best to export a model from Maya to Flash.  Is there a tutorial on how to do this?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm no 3D expert, but as far as I understand it, the 3D support in Flash 10 does not include importing models from other 3D software, like Maya.

The 3D support is kind of internal to Flash and ActionScript, so that one for example can flip a Flash display object in 3D, but there is no import of 3D models, as far as I know.

One alternative you could look into is the open-source 3D library PaperVision3D, which has support for Collada models.

Answer (score 0):

If you  want to import maya like 3D objects in flash, you need to use expernal APIs like papervision3d or away3d. 
Try to use Swift3d which has an swf export option using papervision classes.

Answer (score 0):

and you need yo export from maya as collada file

Answer (score 0):

If you can use WebGL instead of Flash try using www.inka3d.com that exports from Maya to WebGL without coding